# How to parse multidimensional hash variable in Perl

Tags: perl

I have the following multidimensional hash variable

```
my %billingMember ;
$billingMember{1}->{'useremail_quota'} = 10;
$billingMember{1}->{'useremail_blockedquota'} = 5;

$billingMember{2}->{'useremail_quota'} = 10;
$billingMember{2}->{'useremail_blockedquota'} = 5;
```

How can i parse the variable %billingMember ?

ie I need to get each value like

$billingMember{1}->{'useremail_quota'},

$billingMember{1}->{'useremail_blockedquota'} ,

$billingMember{2}->{'useremail_quota'}, ....

Here 1& 2 is just for example, it will dynamic

So i think, we need to use **foreach** or **for**

Comment: What do you mean by “parsing a variable”?

Comment: I need to get each value like $billingMember{1}->{'useremail_quota'},
$billingMember{2}->{'useremail_quota'} ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some samples taken from http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES :

```
 foreach $family ( keys %HoH ) {
     print "$family: { ";
     for $role ( keys %{ $HoH{$family} } ) {
         print "$role=$HoH{$family}{$role} ";
     }
     print "}\n";
 }
```

(Edit : only kept the one which will probably be useful in your case)